How to identify a private key is odd or even from the (x,y) coordinate of the key?
Suppose k is a private key.
Now using elliptic curve cryptography and scaler multiplication point point P(x,y) has been calculated from the private key k
Now if I give someone point P(x,y). Will he/she be able to determine if the key k is odd or even?
